# How should I manage my images for my django app

Tags: python, django, web-development-server, django-staticfiles, static-files

Here I am once again asking a question that might seem stupid:

I am new to web development. So far I've made some practice projects with Django and I've deployed two projects so far as github pages but they were simple static websites (no django).

Now I'm making a web application for my mom's business with Django.
I don't know what I should do with all the images I need for the website.
In the past I have uploaded all jpg and png images to imgur and copied the link in my static websites html

But now I have more images and I am going to pay for a server for them application. I have two types of images:

- Images that will always appear on the page. Because that's part of the design
- Images that the admin can upload when creating a new post for the page

So my question is:

**Should I have all images in the statics folder for my application?**
And call them like this:

```
 <img src="{% static 'website/images/home-slider/myimage.css' %}">
```

And for the other images should I save a similar path in the database?

I just have no idea if things should be done different for production

Comment: where you planning to deploy? in heroku?

Comment: @NavaneethaKrishnan I don't know yet. Why?

Answer (score 1):

Images used as a part of html files are served within static files and images uploaded by the user as a part of creating new post are saved as media files. You usually have seperate static and media root for saving files to avoid confusion.
Media files are served as '/media' as static are served as '/static'.